# NullPointerException while inserting data into SqliteDatabase Android

Tags: android

Android 2.3.3

```
static String name = "Database";
static int version = 1;

static SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
static Cursor c;


public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, name, null, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    sqlDB = getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    sqlDB.execSQL("create table if not exists Operations(Command Text, Pos1 Text, " +
                "Pos2 Text, Pos3 Text, Pos4 Text, Pos5 Text, Pos6 Text, Pos7 Text, Pos8 Text, Pos9 Text, Pos10 Text)");

        insertData();
    }

private void insertData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String addQuery ="ADD, add, and, had, ad, anddd, anndd, null, null, null, null";

                sqlDB.execSQL("insert into Operations values("+ addQuery +")"); 
                     //Exception at the above line
}
```

There are a total of 11 columns.

Can i insert NULL into the database?
If yes, is there any problem with the way i am trying to insert the data into the database?

As pointed out by rekire, it seems the problem is with the getWritableDatabase(). I am calling the constructor with , Database db = new Database(this); which worked in all other projects till now, as i have declared the local variables for name and version and provided null to the factory.

> Answer ::: Sorry it's my mistake. I called a method in the database,
>   by using Database.method(), instead of it's object(db). This made the
>   SQLiteDatabase and Cursor objects to be static in the Database.java
>   file. When i changed it to db.method(), and removed the static
>   keyword, it works fine.

Thanks for your time.. And sorry for the trouble.

Comment: did you check the database is created or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess right than your function `getWritableDatabase()` returns null.

Comment: The only object that can be null in your shown code is `sqlDB` and this one is setted by the function `getWritableDatabase()`. Just a little strange that your `onCreate` does not throw any errors.

Comment: Yeah onCreate doesn't show me any errors and it compiles correctly. It's at the runtime that i am getting the error.

Comment: Try to add a `Log.d("~~test~~", "(sqlDB==null)="+(sqlDB==null));` at the end of your `onCreate` and tell me what is the result in the logcat.

Comment: @VamsiChalla : Take this line `sqlDB = getWritableDatabase();` out of the constructor and put it in the `insertData()` method before you execute the SQL insert command.

Comment: Just a moment...brb.. will reply when i get back

Comment: @rekire I have updated the error log. Can you have a look at it again

Comment: I have found the problem. Updated my question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call the open() method before you make the query

```
mDbHelper.open(); //whitout this call mdb will be NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void insertData() {
    if(sqlDB == null) sqlDB.open();
    String addQuery ="ADD, add, and, had, ad, anddd, anndd, null, null, null, null";
    sqlDB.execSQL("insert into Operations values("+ addQuery +")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB)
```

you should assign `sqlDB = sqlDB;` 
then you can use sqlDB in insertData()

Comment: In general, I will not use the same name with global & local variable...From you coding, I just think sqlDB in onCreate is what you need. And I also agree with others that getWritableDatabase is return null.